# How to estimate the memory consumption of decoding JSON

Tags: php, json, memory

I am loading JSON files into a string and transform the data into an array. The JSON content will be an array of objects with totally variable structure.

What I want is to calculate the memory that will be required to decode the JSON data, to prevent the PHP script from running out of memory (and thus crashing).

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this. You want to parse the JSON incrementally. One of the best utilities I know for doing this is https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser.

When parsed in small doses, you avoid the one-shot memory mess decoding a full json object would require. It's great for processing lots of items in a JSON array.

Comment: My problem is that I finally will need to keep the parsed data in memory. I must be able to search in, process, add to, etc. the whole data.